# python can't find mpi4py in command line but can import it in interpreter mode

Tags: python-2.7, mpi

So I need to use mpi4py to run a module. After manually installed mpi4py and add the path to mpi4py package to python search path through `sys.path.append()` command in .pythonrc. And I tried to import mpi4py in the interpreter and it works fine, no matter where the interpreter is invoked:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, May 23 2013, 17:15:02) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mpi4py import MPI
>>> MPI
<module 'mpi4py.MPI' from '/home/XXXX/yt-x86_64/src/mpi4py-1.3/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mpi4py/MPI.so'>
```

Then I tried to run from command line which a python script containing `from mpi4py import MPI`. It can't find the module:

```
$ python run_rockstar2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_rockstar2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpi4py import MPI
ImportError: No module named mpi4py
```

I've checked that I'm using the same python in the two cases. Anyone has a clue about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your .pythonrc is only checked in interactive mode. You should add the module path to your PYTHONPATH [environment variable](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is fixed!

Comment: If `mpi4py` is located here `/Users/MYUSERNAME/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpi4py/__init__.pyc'`, where do I add this path to? I tried my .bash_profile's `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` variables with no luck